# Typescript switch case with union type

Tags: typescript

Given the following enum and types:

```
export enum MessageType {
  Text = 'TEXT',
  Image = 'IMAGE',
  Pdf = 'PDF',
  File = 'FILE',
}

export type MessageMediaType = MessageType.Image | MessageType.Pdf | MessageType.File;

export interface MessageText {
  type: MessageType.Text;
  // ...
}

export interface MessageMedia {
  type: MessageMediaType;
  // ...
}
```

How can I switch case If I want to achieve something like:

```
switch(message.type) {
  case MessageType.Text: // do something if its a Text Message
    break;
  case MessageMediaType: // do something if its a Media Message - DOES NOT WORK
    break;
  // possible more cases ...
}
```

However the `case MessengerMediaType` does not compile in Typescript.

**'MessengerMediaType' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.**

Is there a more better solution than:

```
switch(message.type) {
  case MessageType.Text:
    // do something if its a Text Message
    break;
  case MessageType.Image:
  case MessageType.Pdf:
  case MessageType.File:
  // do something if its a Media Message
    break;
  // here are more cases but I left it out for simplicity.
}
```

Whats bothering me is that i have defined the union type `MessageMediaType` so I though I can reuse it in the switch case.

How can I achieve this, or any good workaround?

Comment: Because `MessageMediaType` is a union type of `MessageType.Image | MessageType.Pdf | MessageType.File`. Also, your switch/case doesn't make much sense now, since even though Text is part of the union, it will be excluded from the next case since you're breaking the switch once that condition is met. Can you tell us what you're trying to do here?

Comment: If the message is from type `MessageType.Text` I want to handle the text message. If the message is from type `MessageType.Image | MessageType.Pdf | MessageType.File` I want to handle the media message. There are actually even more message types but I reduced it to demonstrate my problem.

Comment: I am aware that I can do a fall through switch case, but I though that Typescript has a more smarter solution to offer I a not aware of.

Comment: Then I cause after the `case MessageType.Text` you can simply use `default` to catch all the other types. If this is the case, perhaps an `if/else` statement will suffice, since you are switching between two binary states: is text, or is not text.

Comment: This switch case is a reduced example. There are more cases than text messages and media messages. I have thought about the default and if/else also. Just asking if there is any possibility to reuse the union `MessageMediaType` as a source of truth.

Comment: Remember that Typescript compiles to Javascript, so you have to solve the problem how you would in Javascript, and then Typescript only tells you whether there is a type error or not.

Comment: @kaya3 Good point